# Is there a way to Convert QTableView model to QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

As you know `QTableView->model()` returns `QAbstractItemModel`. is there a way to fill an instance of `QStandardItemModel` with `QTableView->model()`? or convert `QAbstractItemModel` to `QStandardItemModel`? i need some of `QStandardItemModel` mothods like `clear()` and there is no such thing in `QAbstractItemModel`.

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
model = tblView->model();
```

`error: invalid conversion from ‘QAbstractItemModel*’ to ‘QStandardItemModel*’ [-fpermissive]`

For create table i use this code:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 3, this);

for (int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    model->setRowCount(model->rowCount() + 1);
    model->setData(model->index(i, 0), "...");
    model->setData(model->index(i, 1), "...");
    model->setData(model->index(i, 2), "...");
}
tblView->model() = model;
```

Comment: What model have you established to the QTableView? If that model is different from QStandardItemModel then you must create your own clear() method so you should provide the code for that model. On the other hand, if it is a QStandardItemModel you must cast it: `model = qobject_cas<QStandardItemModel *>(tblView->model());`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks dude, it works. What is `qobject_cast<>();`?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi, if you like to write your comment as Answer. i would more than happy to mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that model is different from `QStandardItemModel` then you must create your own `clear()` method, so you should provide the code for that model. On the other hand, if it is a `QStandardItemModel` you can just cast it:

```
model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(tblView->model());
```